# Weird error (bug?) on my screen

Tags: display, intel-graphics, monitor

I've got a problem.

Here is my laptop spec :

- Type: ASUS A43E-VX389D
- Video Card: Intel HD Graphic
- Memory: 2 GB DDR3
- Processor: Intel B950 ( 2.1 GHz, 2MB L3 cache )

I'm using Ubuntu Precise Pangolin 64-bit, with graphic card, detected as Intel Sandybridge Mobile.

Now, I have the **following error (see images below):**

[image: Error#1]

[image: Error#2]

Sometimes, it's just partial. Sometimes, I could get 'the error' almost a whole screen.

Could somebody help me out?

**FYI**, if I *maximized the window*, the 'error' is sometimes gone. And if it still there, I just minimized/maximized/restored the window till it's gone. And it happens so frequently. To be honest, that's very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You should [report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) (as [this site](https://askubuntu.com/faq#deletion) is [not the right place for bug reports](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/226/are-bug-reports-suitable-for-this-site)).

If you log out, click the Ubuntu logo on the login screen, and select **Ubuntu 2D** instead of **Ubuntu** from the drop-down menu, then you'll log in to a Unity 2D session instead of a Unity session.

Unity and Unity 2D use different window managers, and it seems likely this is either a bug in the window manager or a bug in your graphics drivers that occurs when using a window manager with 3D graphics acceleration.

In addition to giving you a possible workaround, trying this will also give you information you can use in reporting the bug.

Comment: OK, thank you for your fast response Eliah Kagan. FYI, m using Gnome Classic session at the moment. Maybe, yeah, I should report it..

Comment: GNOME Classic uses Metacity as the window manager. It could be a bug in Metacity but seems more likely a bug in your drivers if it's happening with Metacity, since Metacity doesn't use graphics acceleration and is therefore somewhat unlikely to introduce such problems itself.